# In-app Updates API returns inAppUpdatePriority from previous version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, google-play-core

I am implementing **In-app Update API**. Both Flexible and Immediate update flow works fine based on the **update priority**.

But for some reason **AppUpdateInfo** returns **updatePriority** of previouls release.

For Example,

**Build number and its priority set through Google Play Developer API.**

```
   Version code     Priority
1. 109 (Installed)      0
2. 110                  3
3. 111                  5
4. 112                  2
```

**When I check for the update inside the app update priority is of the previous release.**

```
   Update check     Priority
1. 110                  0
2. 111                  3
3. 112                  5
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here because everything is working fine only the update priority that I am getting from In-app Update API has an issue.

Comment: It will be good if you also share your code for reference.

Comment: Could you please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970359/can-we-set-update-priority-for-internal-app-sharingtesting-in-app-updates)? This is my question as well and seems you are able to set the priority.

Comment: @mohit Could you please share the steps to set the priority?

Comment: is it because the app information is cached? or is it because it is internal test?

Answer (score -1):

To determine priority, Google Play uses an integer value between **0** and **5**, with **0** being the default and **5** being the highest priority. To set the priority for an update, use the inAppUpdatePriority field under Edits.tracks.releases in the Google Play Developer API. All newly-added versions in the release are considered to be the same priority as the release. Priority can only be set when rolling out a new release and cannot be changed later.