# Can we set update priority for Internal app sharing(testing in app updates)?

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api, in-app-update

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test),we can use internal app sharing to test in-app updates by performing the following steps:

> 1. Make sure your test device has a version of your app installed that supports in-app updates and was installed using an internal app
>    sharing URL.
> 2. Follow the Play Console instructions to share your app internally. Upload a version of your app that uses a version code that is higher
>    than the one you already have installed on the test device.
> 3. On the test device, click the internal app sharing link for the updated version of your app but do not install the app from the Play
>    Store page that appears after you click the link.
> 4. Open the app from the device's app drawer or home screen. The update should now be available to your app, and you can test your
>    implementation of in-app updates.

But Can we set  the [priority](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#update-priority) for  app version in Internal app sharing? I am displaying flexible or immediate update on the basis of priority.And for production app we can set the priority using the Google Play Developer API as described in the Play Developer API documentation.
But for internal app sharing there is no way mentioned we can test on basis of priority.

Comment: As of now, you can not set update priority for the builds which you share using  Internal App Sharing.

Comment: currently looking answer for this too, so the only possible way is to blind test the flexible or immediate update without priority?

Comment: How to do it both in internal app sharing & production release ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not set `inAppUpdatePriority` for the **Internal App Sharing**.

I have similar logic to determine the `Flexible` and `Immediate` update and I was able to test it with the **[Internal testing track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334#internal_test&zippy=%2Cinternal-test-manage-up-to-testers)** since I'm using [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) to upload the `AAB/APK` to the internal track they also support setting [`in_app_update_priority`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/).

one thing to notice I was able to see the update in the google play store after clearing the play store app cache. but the `AppUpdateManager` inside my app took almost 8 hours until recognize the new update with the right `updatePriority`

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can not set update priority for the builds which you share using Internal App Sharing.

Comment: I edited out the picture because it appears to be irrelevant to the answer.